# how to increase /root partition size from /home in centos

Tags: centos

Below is the file system. its an ftp server and would like to increase root partition.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        29G  5.4G   23G  20% /
tmpfs           3.9G  228K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1      1008M  161M  797M  17% /boot
/dev/sda5       880G   62G  773G   8% /home
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to boot from livecd or usb drive and use the gparted.

Look for details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/489600/gparted-moving-partition-from-beginning-of-disk-to-the-end-of-a-disk)

Comment: can it be possible without data loss?

Comment: There are good chances for that. But gparted always recommends doing a backup, because it can not give 100% warranty

Comment: Like windows , is there any chance to shrink volume from existing partition?

Comment: Yes, gparted can do that